# IndentationError: expected an indented block [Python]

Tags: python, indentation

I got this very simple Python code, but somehow I always get an error:

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

I checked all tabs and spaces twice and I can not find the mistake.

Can someone please give me a hint?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: May be it is not related to your current code? Please post your error line here ?

Comment: line 6 @ShivkumarKondi

Comment: this is the whole code - the whole error message is: File "identidock.py", line 6
    return 'Hello World!\n'
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Maybe you're mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: what do you mean by that? @Dunno

Comment: @watchmerisxe sometimes you get this error if you make some indents by spaces and some by tabs. I'm asking because your code as presented here does not produce this error

Comment: line 6 is correct.

Comment: @Dunno I am using vim, is there any chance to check what I did wrong? 
If I copy paste the code I post here to vim it still gives me the error :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be it is due the editor or improper indentation.

Your code is **perfectly running** in my pc but I would suggest to run the below code

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(port=8080)
```

Answer (score -1):

For me worked this in the docker example.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.debug = True
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```